# How to extract a zip file Asynchronously in c# to not block the UI?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, unzip, zip

There doesn't seem to be a method in C# where you can unzip a file using await, so I created a task and I am trying to await that. I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'
```

When I run this code..

```
Task taskA = await Task.Run(() => ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(tempPath + @"\" + ftpFile, pvtdest));
```

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Keep in mind that by using the async and await keywords this will still be running on the UI thread. It might be better to use a separate thread to run this.

Comment: @mao47: `Task.Run` uses a thread pool thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just remove the `Task taskA =`, like this:

```
await Task.Run(() => ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(tempPath + @"\" + ftpFile, pvtdest));
```

Once you `await` a `Task`, you usually don't need to do anything else. A `Task` doesn't have a result value, so that's why the compiler is complaining about "void". The `await` will handle propagating exceptions and continuing the method when your `Task.Run` is complete, and that should be all you need.

Comment: Thank you, I am self taught and I do not have the best knowledge when it comes to programming but I feel I should have known this. It worked for me, and again thank you.

Comment: Its not about aysnc, ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory method doesn't handle overwrite. It throws exception, any idea how can I select overwrite files or not?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez: I recommend you ask your own question.

Comment: @AgentFire: Since `ZipFile` does not offer an `async` API, a truly asynchronous answer would be hundreds or thousands of lines long. Feel free to add your own answer with a truly asynchronous equivalent.

Comment: @StephenCleary well, the correct answer would be: there is no async solution in the case, just the good old blocking one.

Comment: @AgentFire: That doesn't answer the "not block the UI" part of the question, nor does it answer the "I get the following error" part of the question. Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: It does, and my answer is: its impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(tempPath + @"\" + ftpFile, pvtdest)
}
```

You should include `System.Threading.Tasks;`

Comment: This answer does not handle exceptions well.

Comment: @AgentFire You'd better read the document before leaving the comment.